# Z transform piecewise function

Tags: transformation, z-transform, piecewise-continuity

I have this piecewise function:

$$x(n)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             1  & 0 \leq n \leq m \\
             \\ 0, &\mbox{ for the rest} \\
             \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$$

How do I calculate the $z$-transform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]z^{-n} = \sum_{n=0}^{m}z^{-n} = \frac{1-z^{-(m+1)}}{1-z^{-1}} = \frac{1}{z^{m}}\frac{z^{m+1}-1}{z-1}$, with $z \neq 0$.